# Generate CoreData model from classes

Tags: objective-c, core-data, model

I know you can generate classes from a CoreData model, but is it possible to code the models first and then generate the xcdatamodeld file from my model classes? Types and relationships would be inferred from the object model.

Answer (score 1):

Meaning, write the code for the classes and get a data model from there? Absolutely not. Forget it. The data model contains more than the model classes, so some details can't be specified in a class declaration.

If you don't like the model editor, it's possible to design your model entirely in code. The model editor is intended as a convenience but is not required. But this doesn't mean designing your classes-- this means writing code that uses `NSEntityDescription`, `NSRelationshipDescription`, etc, to build the entire model at run time. I don't know why you'd want to do this, but it's an option.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you could write something to generate the structure, but the model holds more information than the classes so it wouldn't do a complete job. Things like deletion rules on relationships. Indeed, knowing whether to create a relationship or a transformable attribute would be rather hard.

Answer (score 0):

What's possible and what's reasonable are two different things. The xcmodel file format is much simpler (and stricter) than Objective-C, but what you're suggesting would require most of an Objective-C parser (including a C pre-processor and everything else). You're virtually asking for something that takes the LLVM IR and outputs the class definitions as an xcmodel. Using Xcode to create a model is generally much less work than writing class interfaces using Objective-C. This sounds like an exercise in pointless misery.